# Google app scripts looping through range from drag copy

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

How do I loop through user defined rows when they drag copy or paste a range of cells?

I'm trying to develop an onEdit function that watches the sheet for any edits and then logs a 'change date' in the last cell of the row. Every attempt only logs the first changes and not the subsequent row change in the range. Each row is an individual record which needs to have the date of edit recorded.

Many thanks!!

Comment: Is there only two columns, one for editing, one for recording time? If they are more than two columns, the length of rows are all the same?

Comment: Sorry, I was sick yesterday and spent the day in bed. So far I haven't found the solution to my problem (learning Javascript on the fly). I'll post up some of my code in a bit to help everyone understand where I'm at.

Answer (score 0):

The code below achieves what have I understood from your question:

```
function onEdit(e) {
    var time = new Date();
    var timeRecord = time.getFullYear().toString() + '/' + (time.getMonth() + 1).toString() + '/' + time.getDate().toString();
    var recordArea = e.range.offset(0, 1);
    var timeArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < e.range.getNumRows(); i++) {
      timeArray.push([timeRecord]);
    }
    recordArea.setValues(timeArray);
}
```